# Resolving relation does not exist in PostGIS?

Tags: ogr2ogr, postgis-2.0

I have a view, named `PointsForGpxExport`, that contains points I want to export to a GPX file. The `ogr2ogr` command I'm trying to use for the export is included below. When I run the command, a GPX file is created. The file is a shell of a GPX file - headers and root element but none of the data from the view. An error is reported.

The error reported is

```
ERROR 1: ERROR: relation "pointsforgpxexport" does not exist
LINE 1: DECLARE executeSQLCursor CURSOR for SELECT * FROM PointsForG...
```

The command:

```
ogr2ogr-f GPX c:\temp\points.gpx PG:"host=localhost port=5432
dbname=SpatialPlayground schemas=public user=postgres password=password"
-sql "SELECT * FROM PointsForGpxExport"
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM PointsForGpxExport` inside the pgAdmin tool, an error occurs `ERROR: relation "pointsforgpxexport" does not exist` I resolved this error by including the schema name in the query as in `SELECT * FROM "public"."PointsForGpxExport";` This error is identical to the error I'm getting when I run `ogr2ogr` and I thought it would be resolved by using `schemas=public` in the connection string.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1.6, GDAL 1.11.2 released 2015/02/10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a case sensitivity/quoting issue.

`"PointsForGpxExport"` and `PointsForGpxExport` are *not the same table name*.

PostgreSQL, per the SQL standard, case-folds unquoted identifiers. (It case-folds to lowercase, where the standard says uppercase, though). So when you write `PointsForGpxExport`, PostgreSQL treats that as the same as `pointsforgpxexport`. Since table names are case sensitive, and you created your table as `"PointsForGpxExport"` (possibly via a GUI tool that always quotes table names), there's no such table as `pointsforgpxexport`. Hence the error.

When you quote table names, do so consistently - everywhere or nowhere. In this case you need to either:

```
ALTER TABLE "PointsForGpxExport" RENAME TO pointsforgpxexport;
```

or use `"PointsForGpxExport"` in your queries.